# SMO syntax in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, smo

I am trying to use `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo` to extract server values in C#. I'm having difficulty with the syntax.

```
Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection { ConnectionString = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder { DataSource = @"localhost", IntegratedSecurity = true }.ToString() });
Dts.Variables["User::test"].Value = server.AuditLevel____??_____;
```

Trying to use the `Server.AuditLevel`:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.server.auditlevel.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1

Could someone provide an exable using both "get" and "set"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code worked

```
Dts.Variables["User::test"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(server.AuditLevel);
```

The `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlEnum` reference needs to be added as well.